# logstash in docker error "Fail to execute action"

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack

I'm new to the elastic stack and im trying to set it up with RabbitMQ using this guide(but in .NET):
https://piotrminkowski.com/2017/02/03/how-to-ship-logs-with-logstash-elasticsearch-and-rabbitmq/

When I startup Logstash I get the errors

```
[2020-11-14T09:51:50,997][ERROR][logstash.agent ] Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of [0-9], [ \\t\\r\\n], \"#\", \"}\" at line 2, column 16 (byte 35) after input { rabbitmq {\nhost => 192.168", :backtrace=>["/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:32:in `compile_imperative'", "org/logstash/execution/AbstractPipelineExt.java:184:in `initialize'", "org/logstash/execution/JavaBasePipelineExt.java:69:in `initialize'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:47:in `initialize'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:52:in `execute'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:365:in `block in converge_state'"]}

[2020-11-14T09:51:51,296][INFO ][logstash.agent ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}

[2020-11-14T09:51:56,179][INFO ][logstash.runner ] Logstash shut down.

[2020-11-14T09:51:56,209][ERROR][org.logstash.Logstash ] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (SystemExit) exit
```

I don't know what is wrong but I can see that the nhost is "192.168" which probably isnt right, my ip is 192.168.0.29

I'm thankfull for any help

Comment: You have an error in your configuration, probably a typo or some character is missing, update your question with the pipeline configuration that you are using.

Comment: This is the config: docker run -d -it --name logstash logstash -e 'input { rabbitmq { host => "192.168.0.29" port => 30000 durable => true } } output { elasticsearch { hosts => ["192.168.0.29"] } }'

Answer (score 0):

The host option for a rabbitmq input takes a string. A string should be surrounded by double (or single) quotes.

The configuration compiler is quite forgiving, and in many places will accept a "bareword" in place of a string, so it would accept localhost, but you cannot have punctuation in a "bareword", so example.com would result in an error. Likewise, once it sees the periods in the IP address it throws an exception.

Try

```
host => "192.168.0.29"
```

Comment: This is the config

docker run -d -it --name logstash logstash -e 'input { rabbitmq {
host => "192.168.0.29" port => 30000 durable => true } }
output { elasticsearch { hosts => ["192.168.0.29"] } }'